# Windows batch file to move folders based on partial foldername

Tags: windows, batch, search-folder

i want to move folders to other folders based on their partial foldernames

for example:

FolderA\uuu**PM**uu\
FolderA\ii**PM**ddd\
FolderA\ww**PM**ii\
FolderA\uuu**UE**uu\
FolderA\ii**UE**ddd\
FolderA\ww**UE**ii\

all folders *PM*  and subfolders move to FolderA\PostMaster
all Folders *UE* and subfolders move to FolderA\UserExplierence

I´ve tried with several sentences FOR /D ...... but i am not even colse of solution

Thank you!!

My best

UPDATED

I found a solution that makes me happy..i pasted my script (I found that if the folder is located in other drive, you need to add the second SET and CD /D, for working on other drive:

```
SET /P VAR=please type full path folder:  
SET VARA=%VAR:~0,2%
CD /D %VARA% 
CD %VAR%
for /D %%P in (*PM*) do move %%P "%var%\POST MASTER"
for /D %%P in (*UE*) do move %%P "%var%\USER EXPERIENCE"
```

i hope it helps somebody.

Comment: So all folders that have PM in the name sould be moved to olderA\PostMaster and all folders that have UE in the name should be moved to FolderA\UserExplierence

Comment: If you're happy with your solution you should answer your own question.